# How did demon contact Janice while it's locked in a room?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, annabelle-creation

In *Annabelle: Creation* after the Mrs. Mullins explained, we know when girls first enter the house the demon is locked in a room with the Bible pages and can't go out. But the thing I don't understand is how the demon contacted Janice by sending her a message with written pages and unlocked the main door if it can't go outside the bible room.

I mean if it can go out of the room without help just go out and possess the girls right away. Sorry if I miss the part about, but will be glad if someone can explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Even though, that demon possessed that doll, it can move around the house without needing a carrier. It's just like a spirit, a bad one, which can move around without requiring a physical thing. We've seen this in the story told by Esther, mother of Annabelle (Bee).

> **Esther:** **She wanted permission to move into the doll so she could be with us forever.** We said yes, and that's when it became stronger. Soon, we could actually see her. **Only in fleeting glimpses, but it was enough.** Our beloved Bee, our darling. **Even though I couldn't hold her, it was comforting to have the buzz of activity again.**

Here in this story, Annabelle (i.e. the demon) can be seen moving around. That doll was just a temporary house (unless it is a soul) for that demon. Therefore, locking it away wasn't the solution at all. It was attached to doll so hard that it couldn't be separated which is why the doll was locked away and the demon got into hibernation.

It got awakened after sensing the presence of young girls in the house and started to look for the weakest member, which apparently was Janice. Therefore, it started to throw notes around like the time when it asked Mullins to move into the doll.